At nonstandard conditions, how does delta G differ from delta G standard?
A US National Chemistry Olympiad question asked:

The triple point of bromine is 265.9 K and 0.058 bar, and
the standard entropy of vaporization of bromine is 89.0 J
mol-1 K-1. What is the standard enthalpy of vaporization
of bromine?

(A) 17.4 kJ mol-1 
(B) 23.7 kJ mol-1 
(C) 26.5 kJ mol-1 
(D) 30.0 kJ mol-1

For the purposes of this question, I'm fairly sure we can assume that $\Delta H$ and $\Delta S$ change negligibly with temperature. For vaporization of bromine at 265.9 K and 0.058 bar, I was under the impression that $\Delta G$ of vaporization was zero. That's because, if bromine was subjected to those conditions, its vapor pressure would equal the pressure of its surroundings; it would just barely spontaneously vaporize. I don't really see how you could look at it in a way that suggests $\Delta G$ is not zero. With that in mind, the immediate way I see of solving this problem is to use $\Delta G=\Delta H-T\Delta S$. We know $\Delta G=0$, we know $\Delta S=89.0$ J/mol*K, and we know $T=265.9$ K, so it should be a trivial matter to solve for $\Delta H$. But I see that this doesn't make any sense: 265.9 K is just a random boiling point associated with a random pressure. T could just as easily be 500 K, which would completely change the value of $\Delta H$ calculated using $\Delta G=\Delta H-T\Delta S$. So that's the main thing I'm struggling with.
The correct answer to this problem is D, which is arrived at by using $\Delta G^{\circ}= -RTln(K)$ with T=265.9 K and K=0.058. This clearly gives a nonzero $\Delta G^{\circ}$ value, in particular 6300 J/mol. But...what does this even mean? If the reaction we're discussing is clearly taking place at nonstandard conditions, how can you assign it a "standard" change of Gibbs free energy? Then, the equation $\Delta G=\Delta H-T\Delta S$ is used as I described, but with $\Delta G=$6300 J/mol, to yield D as the answer. I'm pretty sure my confusion arises from the difference between $\Delta G$ and $\Delta G^{\circ}$. What exactly are the differences between the two, and can they be unequal when describing certain process that takes place at nonstandard conditions?
